# asp.net gridview AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Can I use AjaxControlToolkit to check whether ASP.NET GridView is Empty or Not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control still renders its [EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx) (or its [EmptyDataText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext.aspx)), so you can't just check if its associated `<table>` element is empty.

You might want to specify a custom `EmptyDataTemplate` that renders an element with a well-known id, then use [$get()](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html) on the client-side to check if that element exists.

You can also create an [extender](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2006/12/12/asp-net-ajax-control-extenders-rolling-your-own.aspx) on the `GridView` that passes its [Rows.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.count.aspx) property to the client side using an [ExtenderControlProperty](http://forums.asp.net/t/1047755.aspx#1480754).

Comment: Is it wise to keep an hidden field, which will be set to RowCount in DataBound event ?. Then check the value using JavaScript.